# java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent: On Adding the view dynamically

Tags: android

In my app i am implementing comment module in which i am adding the layout for comment dynamically as soon as the user post the comment. But i am getting 
**illegalstateException: The specified child already haas parent. you must call removeView() on the child parent's first.**

I am inflating the comment.xml and adding it into the commentsection view.
The code is like this:

```
public void loadCommentUiFragment(List<UserComment> userCommentList){
        View commentView = null;
        if(commentView != null){
            commentSection.removeView(commentView);
        }

        for(UserComment userComment : userCommentList){
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            commentView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.comment_section, null);
            ImageView userImageView = (ImageView) commentView.findViewById(R.id.user_image);
            TextView userNameView = (TextView) commentView.findViewById(R.id.user_name);
            TextView userTimeView = (TextView) commentView.findViewById(R.id.user_time);
            TextView userCommentView = (TextView) commentView.findViewById(R.id.user_comments);

            userNameView.setText(userComment.getUserName());
            userTimeView.setText(userComment.getCreatedAt());
            userCommentView.setText(userComment.getCommentText());

            commentSection.addView(commentView);
        }
        userCommentList.clear();
    }
```

And the **comment.xml** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/post_comment_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        >
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/line_divider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
        android:background="@color/layout_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/user_image"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:background="@color/layout_bg"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line_divider"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="user_name"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Time of comments"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_name"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:maxLength="7"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_comments"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/user_name"
            android:text="comments of the user"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/user_image"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="16dip"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

**main_activity.xml**

```
 <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/commment_section"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_below="@+id/nmd_user_img"
                android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
                >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/pre_comment_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="#90C695"
                    >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/cmt_user_image"
                        android:layout_width="30dip"
                        android:layout_height="30dip"
                        android:layout_margin="5dip"
                        android:padding="2dip"
                        android:background="@color/layout_bg"/>
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/cmt_user_edt"
                        android:layout_width="240dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/cmt_user_image"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
                        android:padding="5dip"
                        android:hint="Enter your comments"/>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="100dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/cmt_user_image"
                        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        >
                        <ImageButton
                            android:id="@+id/post_comment"
                            android:layout_width="90dip"
                            android:layout_height="40dip"
                            android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
                            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
                            android:background="@drawable/post"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </RelativeLayout>
```

I am not getting how to solve this.. The problem with above code is that if i don't call removeView(). It's keep on adding previous view along with new loaded view.

So in **LinearLayout** with id as **commment_section** I am inflating the **comment.xml** dynamically.

Comment: you can maintain array of views to add the previous views, but the remove view is need to be called

Comment: show your fragment code.

Comment: I dont have fragment... basically i have main layout for activity and another layout is comment.xml. In main activity layout commentsection is relativeLayout in that i am inflating the comment.xml layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem with above code is that if i don't call removeView(). It's
>   keep on adding previous view along with new loaded view

To show always new view's layout use `removeAllViews` instead of `removeView` like:

```
if(commentSection != null){
     int childCount=commentSection.getChildCount();
     if(childCount>0)
        commentSection.removeAllViews();
 }
```

> illegalstateException: The specified child already haas parent. you
>   must call removeView() on the child parent's first.

Before adding `commentView` in `commentSection` assign a new id for each View:

```
  int view_id=2015;
  for(UserComment userComment : userCommentList){
    LayoutInflater inflator=(LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                                                       LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View commentView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.alertboxdialog, null);
    commentView.setId(view_id);
    view_id++;
   //.....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Same View object you are adding again it may cause that Exception

Once try as follows in for loop each time take new View

```
for(UserComment userComment : userCommentList){
        LayoutInflater inflator =    (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View commentView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.comment_section, null);
       .............................
       ...............................

        commentSection.addView(commentView);
    }
```

Hope this will helps you.

Answer (score 0):

as per your code you are not trying to add same view (ID) in parent view. You have to create each new `View`.

It's global in your case. try to put inside loop.

```
View commentView = null; [Wrong]
for(....){
    LayoutInflater inflator =    (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View commentView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.comment_section, null);
    commentSection.addView(commentView);
    }
```